# Insert a number after every occurence of a string from a set of strings in a string

Tags: r, regex, string

Let's say I have a set of strings `strset <- c("Apple", "Ball", "Cat1s")`

I'm looking for a way to insert a given number (eg. 21) after every occurrence of a string from `strset` in a new string such as `"[Apple][Ball][Cat1s|Apple][Cat1s|Blah:Ball]"` to convert it to `"[Apple21][Ball21][Cat1s21|Apple21][Cat1s21|Blah:Ball21]"`.

Edit:

`[oneApple][Ball|Balls]` should become `[oneApple][Ball21|Balls]` not `[oneApple21][Ball21|Ball21s]`.

Comment: What should be desired out for text like `[oneApple]` ?

Comment: That's a good question. It should be `[oneApple]` not `[oneApple21]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid replacing strings such `[oneApple]` you need to consider [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) also while building your regex pattern

```
strset<-c("Apple", "Ball", "Cat1s")
str2<-"[Apple][Ball][Cat1s|Apple][Cat1s|Blah:Ball][oneApple][Ball|Balls]"
gsub(paste0("(\\b(?:", paste0(strset, collapse="|"),")\\b)"), "\\121", str2)
```

---

```
//output [1] "[Apple21][Ball21][Cat1s21|Apple21][Cat1s21|Blah:Ball21][oneApple][Ball21|Balls]"
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `paste` with `collapse="|"` and then `gsub` with backreferencing should get the job done.

```
strset<-c("Apple", "Ball", "Cat1s")
str2<-"[Apple][Ball][Cat1s|Apple][Cat1s|Blah:Ball]"
gsub(paste0("(", paste0(strset, collapse="|"),")"), "\\121", str2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `gsub` -

```
strset <- c("Apple", "Ball", "Cat1s")

test <- "[Apple][Ball][Cat1s|Apple][Cat1s|Blah:Ball]"

for(i in strset) {
  test <- gsub(i, paste0(i, "21"), test)
}

test
[1] "[Apple21][Ball21][Cat1s21|Apple21][Cat1s21|Blah:Ball21]"
```

Comment: Wow that was pretty simple. Thanks very much.

Comment: @elborrador Thanks, but a loop is unlikely to be needed. See other answer.

Comment: @Shree - it's possibly still a good idea. Depending on how many strings there are in `strset`, the regex pasting method might fail while this will still sail straight through and complete quickly.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks, good to know. I am not too happy about `gsub` and `paste0` being called in every iteration. Either way, that was the best I could do with my almost non-existent regex skills.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `stringr::str_replace_all`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(strset1, paste0(strset, collapse = "|"), function(m) str_c(m, 21))
#[1] "[Apple21][Ball21][Cat1s21|Apple21][Cat1s21|Blah:Ball21]"
```

**data**

```
strset <- c("Apple", "Ball", "Cat1s")
strset1 <- "[Apple][Ball][Cat1s|Apple][Cat1s|Blah:Ball]"
```

Comment: Plus 1 for use of replacement function. Learnt something new.